# How link between gnuradio and baudline?

Tags: software-defined-radio, software-development, gnuradio

I want to create a sink block in [GNU Radio](http://gnuradio.org) which transfers the signal to [baudline](http://www.baudline.com/). My purpose is viewing SDR's received signal online. How should I program this block?

Answer (score 2):

Just use pavucontrol to redirect the audio output from gnuradio to the audio input of baudline, shouldn't take more than a minute. Creating gnuradio blocks is a mission, and that's without integrating with something like baudline, which I don't even think is possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can install **gr-baz** from https://github.com/balint256/gr-baz (just do according to its readme file), after that u will have the ***baudline sink block*** in Gnuradio.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!